# Чему равно значение выражения -0,8х-(0,6x-0,7y) ,если 2х-у=8

Tags: математика

Чему равно значение выражения -0,8х-(0,6x-0,7y) ,если 2х-у=8

Comment: Если упростить ,то будет -1,4х+0,7у

Comment: подставьте `y+8` вместо `2x`

Comment: @Igor, хм, немного не в тему, но интересно, касаются ли такие темы SO на русском?)))

Comment: Если подставлю ,будет 0

Answer (score 2):

```
-1.4х + 0.7у = -0.7 * (2x - y) = -0.7 * 8 = -5.6
```

Ответ: -5.6